# sudo refuses my password

Tags: 12.04, command-line, password, sudo, gnome-terminal

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now that I want to install a program through the terminal with a command starting with `sudo`, the terminal says `Sorry, try again`.
I just don't get it, this is my user password which I check with through the Software Center.

What can be then wrong? (Is it possible that the terminal function differently than the rest of the OS in relation to ASCII keyboard?)

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Check CAPS LOCK. Passwords are case sensitive.